# Google App Engine - how to prevent exposure of passwords

Tags: google-app-engine, configuration, passwords, environment

I'm using  GAE to run my app. My application uses a password to connect an external service. 
Currently I store this password in a free-text property file which is part of the sources.
Cause I share my sources in git-hub my passwords are exposed

IS there a way to store this kind of sensitive information in GAE configuration / environment (using the admin portal) or something like that.
I guess I can store it somehow in the DataStore, but I'm looking for something simpler like [heroku ENV solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956583/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-heroku-github-and-aws-securing-keys/4956788#4956788)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a separate, `.gitignore`'d, unversioned file that has your passwords in it (say "private.py"). Then, add an example version of this file with placeholder values to your versioned source (say, "private.py.sample").

Comment: that's the way I do it to manage the private API keys used to contact some third party APIs

Comment: the truth is that the situation is more complex: we are 2 developers that use this git repository. so I want we both have the same sources (using .gitignore is a bit problematic when collaborating). I hoped I GAE would support application config

Comment: You don't change your external service passwords that often, do you? Give the other developer a copy of the file with just the passwords in it, have them `.gitignore` it as well, and you'll probably never need to touch that file again. *Don't* put passwords in the same code file as other configuration options.

Comment: In GAE 1.7.6. (released 19th March 2013):
- Apps now have the ability to fopen() files that are declared as static files in app.yaml using the application_readable flag. 
(http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes)

Answer (score 1):

```
class AppConfig(db.Model):
    pass = db.StringProperty()

# ...
cfg = AppConfig.get_by_key_name("MyFirstApplication")
if cfg is None:
    cfg = AppConfig(key_name="MyFirstApplication")
    # this is initial run - request pass from user
    cfg.pass = userInput
    cfg.put()
# here you can use your cfg.pass
```